# Can I store intermediate results?

Tags: gpu, theano

I want to store intermediate results to avoid multiple calculations for one thing. What I'm looking for is something like this:

```py
    h1_activ = sigmoid(self.bias_visiblie + T.dot(D, self.W))
    h1_sample = h1_activ > rnds.uniform((n_samples, self.n_hidden )) 

    f_h1_sample = theano.function(
        inputs=[D],
        outputs=h1_sample,
        # I'd like to take the result from 'h1_sample' and store it into 'H1_sample'
        updates=[(self.H1_sample, ??? )] 
    )
```

The code above does not run of course but is there a way to do something like this? Storing an intermediate value into a shared variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the final results, which use the same intermediate results, in the same `theano.function`.

For example:

```
h1_activ = sigmoid(self.bias_visiblie + T.dot(D, self.W))
h1_sample = h1_activ > rnds.uniform((n_samples, self.n_hidden )) 
# h2_sample use the intermediate result h1_sample.
h2_sample = h1_sample * 2

f_h1_sample = theano.function(
    inputs=[D],
    outputs=[h1_sample, h2_sample],
)
```

h2_smaple is a final result which uses h1_sample.

Also you can save the intermediate results and use them as inputs in another `theano.function`.

Different `theano.function`s correspond to different computation graphs. I think no calculation can be shared between different computation graphs.

Comment: Hi! When you say "*you can write the final results*" I don't know how I would do that. I don't want to shuffle too much data between the GPU and CPU RAM, so how would I store an intermediate result after the execution of a graph most efficiently on the GPUs RAM?

Comment: @displayname    I add an example in the original answer.

Comment: But won't this copy the data back to the host?